# Find bit-depth of an AVAsset with audio encoded in linear PCM

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-encoding

Given an `AVAsset` representing a movie that has at least one audio track one can determine various **properties** of this audio track by obtaining an `AudioStreamBasicDescription` instance corresponding to it:

```
AVAssetTrack audio_track =  [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescriptionRef = [audio_track.formatDescriptions objectAtIndex:0];
AudioStreamBasicDescription *ASBD = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(formatDescriptionRef);
```

this instance (ASBD) can then be examined, for example:

```
ASBD->mFormatID == kAudioFormatLinearPCM  // True if the track is PCM
ASBD->mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian // nonzero if the format is big endian
```

However I cannot seem to find a way to determine the bit-depth of the sample. This is necessary as it will be supplied as a value for the key `AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey` in a dictionary that will get passed as output settings to `+[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType: outputSettings:]`.

How may this information may be extracted from an `AVAsset` or an `AVAssetTrack`?

(The context is re-encoding the video in an `AVAsset`, but leaving the audio as-is)

Answer (score 0):

The bit depth is stored in `ASBD->mBitsPerChannel`